# How do i get timeRangeEndDate and timeRangeStartDate in java?

Tags: java, arrays, list, dictionary

[image]

Output from viewConfiguration is:- `com.idi.qa.pojoclasses.viewsAPI.ViewConfiguration@5740ff5e[categories=Category Behavior contains /Authorization or Category Object contains /Host/Application/Workflow,summary=Activity lifecycles plotted over time,timeRangeDef=Last 30 days,**timeRangeEndDate=1553731199999,timeRangeStartDate=1553644800000**,viewtype=<null>]`

How to get timeRangeEndDate and timeRangeStartDate?? Can I use List ??

Comment: Your question is not really clear, but by the looks of it the values you want are part of the ViewConfiguration class. Does the class not have Getters for those 2 values?

Comment: No getters and setters, Can I store the output of viewConfiguration in List/ Map and then can I get those two values..??

Comment: If the class doesn't provide you any publicly accessible methods to get those values it first of all is usually a sign that whoever designed the Class doesn't think making these 2 values available outside of the class scope is necessary or useful. Accessing a field that you are usually not supposed to access is something you can do with java reflection.

Comment: then what changes I can do So that I can get those two values??

Comment: What he has added is o/p of application, which should be highlighted as code

Comment: Any Solutions guys ??